# Implementation of the Linux find command in python

Tags: python, subprocess

Can someone point me to a set of instructions of how to actually implement and utilize the `find` command within a Python script?

I have looked at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
I'm not exactly sure how to utilize the command, even if implementation goes well with either `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`. From all of the SO threads that I've read concerning this topic, it seems like these are the two best options.  However, I am not sure what kind of arguments I would need to use, as well as how to specifically implement the `find` command within them.

Can someone please demonstrate how to use `find` in the context of `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen` so that I can later call `find` directly in my Python script?

Comment: What have you tried? Show [some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Describe what is wrong: what do you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `check_output()` helper function.

```
find_output = subprocess.check_output('find ~', shell = True)
```

In the above example, `find_output` will contain a `bytes` instance of the `find` commands `stdout`. If you wish to capture the `stderr` as well, add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
found = subprocess.Popen(['find', '.'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(found.stdout.readline, ''):
   print line,
```