# Invoking and using Linux find correctly with a database in python

Tags: python, linux, ftp, find

I asked a similar question but left out the database part:

[Implementation of the Linux find command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990267/implementation-of-the-linux-find-command-in-python)

The problem with most of these answers is that `subprocess` methods do correctly implement find but only can search within my computer. I'm trying to search in an ftp database and have attempted the following types of things:

```
find_output = subprocess.check_output('find ~', shell = True)
```

into

```
find_output = subprocess.check_output('find ' + sitename, shell = True)
```

or

```
find_output = subprocess.check_output('find ' + sitename, filename, shell = True)
```

among other attempts, but nothing has worked so far. I am trying to search for a specific file or directory within directories and subdirectories in an ftp database and printing out the pathway. Is there a useful method that is not `subprocess` or is there a way to correctly adapt `subprocess` to accept the additional arguments (sitename, filename)?

Comment: What is an "ftp database"?

Comment: I have connected to a database using ftp (file transfer protocol) (ftplib). I don't have admin privileges though.

Comment: But ftp is not a database. It's a means of transferring files between computers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I have access to the database with the python script and can look through it, so essentially I can access the files.

Answer (score 0):

try using a list for the command elements

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["find", ".", "-name", "*.py"])
b'./docs/conf.py\n./setup.py\n'

>>> help(subprocess.check_output)
Help on function check_output in module subprocess:

check_output(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs)
    Run command with arguments and return its output.
...
```

Re-reading your question you'll want to use an ftp client to connect to the ftp server and look at the files there.

See the Python 3 [ftplib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html)

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> with FTP("ftp1.at.proftpd.org") as ftp:
...     ftp.login()
...     ftp.dir()
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand both what the final arguments are and what these: (*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs) mean. Could you please explain?

Comment: `*popenargs` means it takes a list of args. `check_output` calls `subprocess.Popen` so it passes popen args to it.  See the example above the help which passes a list of args. After re-reading your question it looks like you might want to use Python's ftplib to make the FTP connection and use that to look for your files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few problems you need to address:

1) As you noted, find on linux execute local to the machine it's run on. 
2) You trying to access a remote FTP file system (I presume).

If you remote system is linux and you want to go through its file system using find, remotely you'll need to connect to that machine. SSH may be a good example. I just modified from one the answer on your original question.

```
found = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'user@host', 'YOUR FIND CMD'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(found.stdout.readline, ''):
   print line,
```

Comment: If it's possible, could you please include an argument for the file that is being searched for? Or if it isn't needed, could you explain why?

Comment: This would be dependent on your implementation of find (Where I mentioned YOUR FIND CMD) for instance using ' find / -name "foo.txt" ' would search your system for any file called foo.txt.

Comment: And with an ftp server, is the host going to be a url of the ftp site, an ip-address, or something else?